# pandas GroupBy plotting each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I have some data from which I want to extract a time series of revenues (sum of `Dollars` in different dates `Day` over different locations `Where`) for different products (`x` and `y`).

```
import pandas as pd

#Create data
data = {'Day': [1,1,2,2,3,3],
        'Where': ['A','B','A','B','B','B'],
        'What': ['x','y','x','x','x','y'],
        'Dollars': [100,200,100,100,100,200]}

index = range(len(data['Day']))

columns = ['Day','Where','What','Dollars']


df = pd.DataFrame(data,  index=index, columns=columns)
df
```

[image: ddd]

To do so, I group data by `Day` and `What` and sum over `Dollars`:

```
#Group by Day and What and sum Dollars (for each Where)
print(df.groupby(['Day', 'What'])['Dollars'].sum())
```

[image: ccc]

Now, I would like to make a time series for `x` and `y` like so:

[image: iii]

I tried the following, but it is clearly not working:

```
items = df.What.unique()

ax = plt.figure()
for item in items:
    df_tmp = df[['Day']][df.What == item]
    plt.plot(df_tmp['Day'],df_tmp,'.-',label=item)
```

[image: fff]

Can someone, please, put me in the right direction?
Is there a faster way to get to the right result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, `unstack`, and plot:

```
(df.groupby(['Day', 'What'])['Dollars']
   .sum()
   .unstack('What', fill_value=0)
   .plot())
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Superfast Express..!! +1 :)

Comment: @coldspeed Do you know I can slice the resulting dataframe? E.g., I want to get the first time series but `df[:][0]` does not work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @shamalaia `df.iloc[:, 0]`